# CollectionView duplicate cell when loading more data

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, collectionview

**The problem:**

I have a CollectionView which loads a UIimage into each cell. However my problem is that when I load additional cells with more images they appear to duplicate. I can't quite see what could be causing this in my code.
Might it be because of some problem with reusable cells?

Can anyone see why this occurs?

**NOTE:** The array with the images doesn't have duplicates

**Video of problem:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjRsFc8DDmI

**Image of the problem:**

[image: CollectionView has duplicate cell when loading more data]

**Here are my functions for collectionView:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    if self.movies == nil
    {
      return 0

    }

    return self.movies!.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
    let cell =    
      collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, 
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UpcomingCollectionViewCell

   if self.movies != nil && self.movies!.count >= indexPath.row
    {
        // Calc size of cell
        cell.frame.size.width = screenWidth / 3
        cell.frame.size.height = screenWidth / 3 * 1.54

        let movies = self.movies![indexPath.row]
        if(movies.posterPath != "" || movies.posterPath != "null"){
        cell.data = movies.posterPath
        }
        else{
        cell.data = nil
        }
        // See if we need to load more movies
        let rowsToLoadFromBottom = 5;
        let rowsLoaded = self.movies!.count
        if (!self.isLoadingMovies && (indexPath.row >= (rowsLoaded - rowsToLoadFromBottom)))
        {
            let totalRows = self.movieWrapper!.totalResults!
            let remainingMoviesToLoad = totalRows - rowsLoaded;
            if (remainingMoviesToLoad > 0)
            {
                self.loadMoreMovies()
            }
        }
}
   else
{
        cell.data = nil
}

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3*1.54)
}
```

**Here I load the data from a Wrapper class:**

```
func loadFirstMovies()
{

    isLoadingMovies = true

    Movies.getMovies({ (movieWrapper, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            // TODO: improved error handling
            self.isLoadingMovies = false
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Could not load first movies \(error?.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.addMoviesFromWrapper(movieWrapper)
        self.activityIndicator.hidden = true
        self.isLoadingMovies = false
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

func loadMoreMovies(){

    self.isLoadingMovies = true
    if self.movies != nil && self.movieWrapper != nil && self.movieWrapper!.page < self.movieWrapper!.totalPages
    {
        // there are more species out there!
        Movies.getMoreMovies(self.movieWrapper, completionHandler: { (moreWrapper, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                // TODO: improved error handling
                self.isLoadingMovies = false
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Could not load more movies \(error?.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            print("got more!")
            self.addMoviesFromWrapper(moreWrapper)
            self.isLoadingMovies = false
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}

func addMoviesFromWrapper(wrapper: MovieWrapper?)
{
    self.movieWrapper = wrapper
    if self.movies == nil
    {
        self.movies = self.movieWrapper?.results
    }
    else if self.movieWrapper != nil && self.movieWrapper!.results != nil
    {
        self.movies = self.movies! + self.movieWrapper!.results!
    }
}
```

And lastly I call: `loadFirstMovies()` in `viewDidLoad()`

EDIT:
**The UpcomingCollectionViewCell**

```
class UpcomingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


var data:String?{
    didSet{
        self.setupData()
    }
}

func setupData(){

   self.imageView.image = nil // reset the image

    if let urlString = data{
        let url =  NSURL(string: "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + urlString)
        self.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)


      }
    }  
 }
```

Comment: please show the code of your `UpcomingCollectionViewCell`...

Comment: I've updated the question with UpcomingCollectionViewCell

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a typical table view/collection view setup issue.

Any time you recycle a cell using a dequeue method like `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`, you must always fully configure all the views in the cell, including setting all the text fields/image views to their starting values. Your code has several if statements where, if the condition of the if is false, you don't set up the views in the cell. You need to have else clauses that clear out old content from the cell's views in case there is content left over from the last time the cell was used.

### EDIT:

Change your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method to begin like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
    let cell =    
      collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, 
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UpcomingCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = nil;  //Remove the image from the recycled cell
//The rest of your method ...
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with else statements in "cellForItemAtIndexPath" It still results in some cells being duplicated. But does not happen so often compared to before (without else)?

Comment: To make that work you'd also need André Slotta's change to setupData (where you set the imageView's image to nil before loading a new image.)

Comment: I've added "André Slotta's" change as-well but cells are now empty and not loaded with a new image. I've made a short video of its current state please see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjRsFc8DDmI.  The code is also updated

Comment: This worked! But I don't understand why it didn't work before :)

Comment: Reread my original answer carefully. I told you what you needed to do. **YOU MUST ALWAYS CONFIGURE A RECYCLED CELL COMPLETELY.** There were paths though your code that did not, and in those cases, the image left over from the last time the cell was used would still be in the recycled cell. In the code I added, I explicitly set the cell's imageView.image to nil before beginning the `if` statements. That way the image view always starts out as nil, no matter how the code passes through your if statements.

Comment: Note: This issue bites nearly all iOS developers more than once. It takes some getting used to.

Comment: Thanks for the help solving this

Comment: If I clear the images in the collectionView(..) call as well, some of my images (when fast swiping) become blank. Maybe because I am resetting them to nil already just before loading them from the url?

Comment: why not just hide the cell?

Answer (score 2):

in your custom cells `setupData()` method try the following:

```
func setupData(){
  self.imageView.image = nil // reset the image

  if let urlString = data{
    let url =  NSURL(string: "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + urlString)
    self.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
  }
}
```

Comment: This clears the cells image, but results in some cells being empty.

Comment: well... if there IS an `urlString` that leads to an actual image file and the `hnk_setImageFromURL` method works as expected this code should definitely work.

Comment: hnk_setImageFromURL is from the "Haneke" lib so I expect that to work and urlString also leads to an actual image file?

Comment: You want to clear the image to begin with, and then let your hnk_setImageFromURL call install an image once it loads.