# Duplicate data from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application works with a **collectionView** inside a **tableView**. The **collectionView** works in the horizontal scroll display for photos, the **tableView** works for the mappings of posts to scroll vertically. I also built an indicator for the number of images displayed in each of the posts. One post may contain up to 5 pictures, for example:

**1st post** - 2 pictures (**Apple, orange**), showing these 2 photos and possible to scroll 2 photos

**2nd post** - 3 pictures (**banana, pineapple, pear**), displays these 3 pictures and possible to scroll 3 photos

**3rd post** - 4 pictures (**pomegranate, apricot, plum, kiwi**), displays these 4 pictures and possible to scroll 4 pictures

**4th post** - 5 photos (**raisins, melon, watermelon, cucumber, tomato**), but the **4th post** displays the images from the 1st post, ie (**Apple, orange**), but display images shows **5 photos**, however, I can only scroll through **2 photos** and the images displayed are (apples, oranges).

Also, if scrolling on the 1st post, scrolling happens automatically on the 4th post as well.

This may be a problem with the **database** or it is a problem with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CollectionView duplicate cell when loading more data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674788/collectionview-duplicate-cell-when-loading-more-data)

Comment: I dont thinks its a database issue. Its more how you are displaying the cells. Several other people had that issue as well with duplicate cells. Unless you can see in your database snapshot, double entries. 
Some code would help

Comment: Without code we can't help you. Most likely, this issue is related to the fact that cells are reused in a tableView & collectionView. So look at the above question if it resolves your issues it's duplicate. If it does not resolve your issue show us your tableView & collectionView code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try, if it not help me, I will add code in my question